# Magento 2: Missing Invoice Sequence Id's

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I'm currently running an Magento 2.2.9 shop and investigate an issue where invoice sequence numbers gone missing.

For example we have an order and by simply clicking the send invoice button, the System creates an new invoice with the old one nowhere to be found.

So I investigated this in the Database:

```sql
SELECT entity_id,increment_id FROM `sales_invoice` where increment_id BETWEEN 'OS-R-045315' and 'OS-R-045317'
```

[image]

As you can see `OS-R-045316` is clearly missing.

So my questions are:

- Why does magento delete invoices? What could trigger such an behavior?
- Is there any audit trail, where i can find missing invoice sequences?
- Is there an way to ensure all invoice numbers could be found within magento?